# How to parser SQL string with self defined functions using jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to parse *SQL* string with [jOOQ SQL parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/). The *SQL* contains self defined functions like this:

```sql
select dateadd([*]'20190809', 'yyyymmdd', 1) from table1
```

It can't be parsed with any dialect. 
I want to get the select fields and manipulate the limit-offset clause.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Which SQL dialect (RDBMS vendor) is it you are working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The somewhat standard `DATEADD()` function (`DATE_ADD()` in some SQL dialects) takes very many different forms, depending on the specific SQL dialect.

jOOQ's SQL parser currently only supports one of these variations: `DATEADD(<datepart>, <interval>, <date>)`, which corresponds to the syntax in SQL Server (and some other dialects).

Applied to your example (assuming you want to add one day) this would be:

```sql
select dateadd(DAY, 1, date '2019-08-09') from table1
```

Note that the `'20190809'` isn't a proper date literal in most dialects, which is why I substituted it with `date '2019-08-09'`.

Also note that you can play around with these things using the [jOOQ translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/).

Assuming you have your own user-defined stored procedure also called `DATEADD`, then you are indeed out of luck, as jOOQ's parser attempts to parse the expression as described above. With any other name (e.g. `DATEADD1`) jOOQ's parser would not have any problem parsing this expression. You might however want to configure how jOOQ should [deal with unknown functions](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#withParseUnknownFunctions(org.jooq.conf.ParseUnknownFunctions)).